# %N$d format in sprintf not working in gnuplot

Tags: printf, gnuplot, abort

I just enter gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 4 Linux x86_64 13/10/02

and run the following commands:

```
gnuplot> a=1;b=2
gnuplot> print sprintf("Testing: %1$d %1$d",a,b)
```

Resulting in an ouput of "Testing: 1 2" instead of "Testing: 1 1". Apparently the `n$` parameter is not working

Furthermore if `%2$d` is invoked in the format string then gnuplot exits abnormally (aborted) with core. It prompts:

> *** Invalid %N$ use detected *** (Aborted, 'core' generated)

Is that a bug or simply `%N$d` cannot be invoked in gnuplot?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, so report it to the gnuplot team?

Comment: Correct, `n$` doesn't work and won't ever work because internally gnuplot tokenizes the sprintf format and formats the specifiers one by one.

Comment: Thanks, Hence I will try the hard way: needed to repeat multiple times an "index %d" directive on the same sprintf.